# Softmax input or output SecondStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor/BiasAdd/softmax has invalid batch

Tags: python, intel, openvino

We have trained a `Mask R-CNN` model on a `NVIDIA GPU` to do object instance segmentation and tested on some images with sufficient performance. Now we are looking into deploy the trained model on `Neural Compute Stick 2`. I'm just getting started with `OpenVINO toolkit` and here is what I have done:

- I downloaded `mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.tar.gz` from `TensorFlow detection model zoo` and decompressed it.
- I used `ModelOptimizer` as follows to get an `Intermediate Representation`:

  ```
  python3 mo_tf.py \
  --input_model ./frozen_inference_graph.pb \
  -- tensorflow_use_custom_operations_config extensions/front/tf/mask_rcnn_support.json \
  --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config ./pipeline.config \
  --data_type FP16
  ```

(I used data type of FP16 as the default FP32 is not supported on VPU)

- Then I used Inference Engine in the `mask_rcnn_demo` as follows:

`./mask_rcnn_demo -m ./frozen_graph.xml -i ./image.jpg -d MYRIAD`
However, I got the following error:

```
[ ERROR ] [VPU] Softmax input or output 
SecondStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor/BiasAdd/softmax has invalid batch
```

Could someone please point me to the source of this error?

I understand from the documentation that currently Mask RCNN is only supported on CPU and GPU, but I would like to know is there anything I can do to get it run on VPU (such as write custom layers for layers not supported in Model Optimizer?). I haven't found any explanation on why Mask RCNN is not supported on VPU in the documentation yet.

Thanks,

Comment: original question is here https://software.intel.com/es-es/node/800449

Answer (score 0):

give a try with **HETERO plugin**

-d HETERO:MYRIAD, CPU